# Using QSqlTableModel and QTableView model and view layout, is it possible to have a Column in my table to hide rows

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlite, pyqt, pyqt5

Using QSqlTableModel and QTableView, is it possible  to have a Column (int) in my table and when I enter "1" on a row in that column, that row is then hidden from the tableview, but not deleted from the DB.
What I am trying to achieve is a temp situation where the row hidden and  is not yet deleted from the DB, and can be held in that position until (if still needed) the hidden row is unhidden or (not needed) the row is deleted permanently from the DB, a sort of undelete situation.

I have looked at sqlite3 to see if there is any way of tagging a row so it is not shown when called by qt, I have also looked at other parts of qt, but not much information around on the net or any new up to date books to learn from, I am asking if anyone knows of a workaround or has tried this method with another qt function, I am unaware of how many of these functions work.

Comment: I do not understand you, could you explain me better

Comment: I have a qtableview db with columns “id”, “col1”, “col2”, “col3”, “col4”, “hide”. The idea is to use the hide column as a reference column e.g. when you enter a value of 1 then that row which relates to that entry is hidden from tableview.  It is not deleted from the Database just hidden from tableview, or not shown in tableview.  Is this possible using python3 PyQt5 sqlite3.  I know it can be done in PHP MySql,

Comment: 1) From what I understand you, your table has a hide field and if the user types a "1" the corresponding row must be hidden. Am I right? 2) If the above is correct then it should be hidden as soon as the user types "1" or after typing "1" and pressing the enter key? 3) Going a little further from the question, if the user wants to show the hidden row again as he would?

Comment: Thank you for answering.
First off. The “id” & “hide” columns are view.hideColumn()
1) Yes that is correct, this is done by button.clicked.connect(HideView) this puts the 1 in the hide field of the selected row.
You select Row click button – row hidden.
2) Another button.clicked.connect(ShowColumn) to view & edit hide Column, using same button to hidecolumn again

Comment: 1) I understood that the row is selected and the button is pressed to set the "1" and hide the selected row, 2) How do you indicate the row that is going to be shown returned since there are possibly several hidden rows?

Comment: Please edit your question as this information is relevant, read [ask] and pass the [tour] so that you know the SO logic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible solution is use a [`QSortFilterProxyModel`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsortfilterproxymodel.html) to hide the row:

```py
import random
import string
from functools import partial

from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets, QtSql


def randomString(stringLength=10):
    """Generate a random string of fixed length """
    letters = string.ascii_lowercase
    return "".join(random.sample(letters, stringLength))


def createConnection():
    db = QtSql.QSqlDatabase.addDatabase("QSQLITE")
    db.setDatabaseName(":memory:")
    if not db.open():
        QtSql.QMessageBox.critical(
            None,
            QtWidgets.qApp.tr("Cannot open database"),
            QtWidgets.qApp.tr(
                "Unable to establish a database connection.\n"
                "This example needs SQLite support. Please read "
                "the Qt SQL driver documentation for information "
                "how to build it.\n\n"
                "Click Cancel to exit."
            ),
            QtWidgets.QMessageBox.Cancel,
        )
        return False

    query = QtSql.QSqlQuery()
    query.exec_(
        """
        CREATE TABLE "mytable" (
            "id"    INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
            "col1"  TEXT,
            "col2"  TEXT,
            "col3"  TEXT,
            "col4"  TEXT,
            "hide"  INTEGER
        );
    """
    )

    for _ in range(10):
        query = QtSql.QSqlQuery()
        query.prepare(
            """INSERT INTO mytable (col1, col2, col3, col4) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?);"""
        )
        for _ in range(4):
            query.addBindValue(randomString())
        query.exec_()
    return True


FILTER_VALUE = 1


class HideProxyModel(QtCore.QSortFilterProxyModel):
    def filterAcceptsRow(self, sourceRow, sourceParent):
        col = self.sourceModel().fieldIndex("hide")
        ix = self.sourceModel().index(sourceRow, col, sourceParent)
        return ix.data() != FILTER_VALUE


class Widget(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Widget, self).__init__(parent)
        button = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Hide", clicked=self.onClicked)
        self.m_view = QtWidgets.QTableView(
            selectionBehavior=QtWidgets.QAbstractItemView.SelectRows
        )
        self.m_model = QtSql.QSqlTableModel()
        self.m_model.setTable("mytable")
        self.m_model.select()

        self.m_proxy = HideProxyModel()
        self.m_proxy.setSourceModel(self.m_model)
        self.m_view.setModel(self.m_proxy)

        lay = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)
        lay.addWidget(button)
        lay.addWidget(self.m_view)

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def onClicked(self):
        rows = set(
            self.m_proxy.mapToSource(ix).row()
            for ix in self.m_view.selectedIndexes()
        )
        self.m_view.clearSelection()
        col = self.m_model.fieldIndex("hide")
        for row in rows:
            rec = self.m_model.record(row)
            rec.setValue(col, FILTER_VALUE)
            self.m_model.setRecord(row, rec)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)

    if not createConnection():
        sys.exit(-1)

    w = Widget()
    w.resize(640, 480)
    w.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Hi eyllanesc, you are a star... just what I asked for, I will be putting it to a full test to check how it works with sqlite DB, I have not the experience in python3 pyqt5 to have done this, thank you very much indeed for your help.